# Is it legal to develop and sell software that operates in a similar fashion to available software?

Tags: intellectual-property, software

I'm currently working on a project that can provide remote desktop assistance like [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/). There are many programs already available providing similar services [(like these programs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software).  I wrote all code myself.

Can I sell my program or it's not legal because there are already programs providing same features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle it's legal to sell software that acts like VNC.

Better then that: [Older versions of the VNC protocol (RFB) are open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol#History), and the protocol details are well documented, which would make it hard for anyone to say "your remote viewing software is infringing on our IP."

Answer (score 5):

It's legal to sell your program if it doesn't infringe any law or anyone else's intellectual property.  Examples of things that can get you into trouble:

1. [statutes](/questions/tagged/statutes): Some countries have export laws that forbid you to distribute certain types of encryption without proper export controls.
2. [patents](/questions/tagged/patents): If you use a design or invention that is under patent protection you could be liable for infringing patent rights.
3. [trademark](/questions/tagged/trademark): If you improperly use a trademarked name you could be subject to damages.
4. [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing): If you violate a license to which you have agreed you can be sued for damages.
5. [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright): If you appear to have copied something without license you can be liable for damages.
6. Just because: [If someone wants to sue you, they can](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/224/10).

Since there's no way to guarantee your business won't run into liability from infringement – or from some other failure – people normally conduct [business](/questions/tagged/business) through entities like LLCs that shield them from personal liability.  Depending on their concerns and finances, they may also:

- Buy liability [insurance](/questions/tagged/insurance)
- Consult professionals like IP lawyers to:

  1. review their business and products in advance to look for and address glaring infringements, and/or
  2. correctly protect their IP using the tools mentioned above.